# Can i create multiple materials for single face

Tags: materials

Can I create multiple materials for a single face of the thing like circle?

Creating some pattern like square or other circle boxes on the circle to apply different materials on them.

Or can we create  a simple circle with sub meshes (if that's the right with terminology), in a similar way as said for creating a pattern of boxes(square/circles) so that these squares or circles are different meshes so that they can be colored or textured differently?

Complete noob at model making, first question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't directly apply multiple materials to a single face, you can use a texture map to control how two different materials appear on a face.

---

## Blender Render:

Make sure your object has a material.

[image]

Click the *Use Nodes* button.

[image]

Drag out a new panel.

[image]

Change the panel to the *Node Editor*.

[image]

Add a *MixRGB* node...

[image]

...and plug it in like so.

[image]

Duplicate the *Material* node and plug it in to the *MixRGB* node. Make sure to assign both nodes their own materials.

[image]

Customise both materials to your liking. Notice that dragging the *MixRGB* slider left or right changes which *Material* node the final material uses. 0 corresponds to the top node, and 1 corresponds to the bottom node.

[image]

Create a new texture in the data textures list.

[image]

Customise the texture to your liking, or import a UV map for more control.

[image]

Add a *Texture* node from *Add* --> *Inputs* --> *Texture*, and plug in the *Value* output into the *MixRGB* node. Notice that the black parts of the texture correspond to the top *Material* (value 0) and the white parts correspond to the bottom node (value 1).

[image]

Voilà! Rendering an image shows that it mixes the materials regardless of the faces!

[image]

---

The same concept can be applied to Cycles; just replace the Material nodes with a shader node tree each.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign two materials on one face obviously. How would you determine the boundaries? What you can is create mask (black and white image) and use it as factor for blending two materials.
[image]

Comment: Can i create a single mask or many and will i be able to change the color of the mask when i import this thing in unity3d

Comment: This work in Blender only. For export to Unity (or any other 3D software or game engine) you need bake colors to texture. This texture you can use for coloring object out of Blender. There are no "one click solution". Here is awesome tutorial how to mix textures/colors/materials in Blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liNGmdXsfbs&list=PLOg_Sr7fkqte01FyBCUNaRPsTkw0Wuz8A       And here you can see how to bake textures and maps for using in game engines. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPy-oNtorus

Answer (score 0):

You could give the material a texture (and use a specific image editor like GIMP to make a nice texture) after giving it a material.  You may or may not need to UV unwrap the object so that the texture looks proper on the model however.  This is what the texture panel would look like:

[image: Texture panel]

You could also create the actual geometry that you are trying to achieve in Edit Mode.  While in Edit Mode, you can use the assign button in the Materials Tab to set a particular material to the faces you have selected.  Something like this:

[image: Materials]

Which way to go can depend very heavily on what you are trying to achieve.  If you are trying to make a flat plane with a pattern, use a texture so that you do not unnecessarily increase the vertex count (taking longer to render).  If you have a tree with leaves that are going to be just one color, then go with the different materials.

Comment: Have you applied the red and blue textures on the face of the cube .without altering the shape of the face of the cube .

Comment: @SouravSachdeva I am unsure what you mean by the shape, but I used inset (press "i" with a face selected) to make the smaller square (flush with the surface), then assigned the blue material to it.  In Unity, you would then need to add another material slot (just change a number and drop in the Blue material).  If you would like, I can elaborate on the texture UV unwrapping process (though there are many tutorials out there on that) and assigning materials for easy use in Unity.