# Multiple materials on one object separated with textures

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have a mesh where there will be multiple black and white textures on it, and will each set the value a shader that will appear on the mesh in different areas. **So wherever the texture is painted, the material will appear there, for short.**

I know this set up won't work, but it's an example of what I want to be done:
[image]

The **first** (material output setup) will show a material/color from the `Principled BSDF` shader wherever `1Image` is painted (as in probably a black color will be painted on a white texture, or whatever works) on the mesh.

The **second**, the `Diffuse BSDF` shader will only show it's purple color wherever the `2Image` is painted on the mesh.

The **third** will have hair grow, hopefully on a scale where black has a full weight, and grey a medium weight, and white no weight. Full weight as in most dense where the hair grows. This will also be wherever those shades are painted on 2Image (supposed to be 3Image, forgot to change it).

**So how do I set up a node system that can get this fake set-up to actually work?**

Also, I know I could just `Weight Paint` where the hair grows, but I am limited to only the vertices, and on a low poly mesh, it's hard to be more detailed.

Comment: Here's a possible answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/748/15140 and here's some related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/can-i-create-multiple-materials-for-single-face, or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/how-to-apply-a-material-e-g-dirt-over-an-object-that-already-has-multiple-mat?rq=1

Comment: I am using Cycles, but I may be able to reference those. Not sure how to get it to work with the hair and more materials too.

Comment: Distribution of hairs can't be controlled in the material (except you fake the effect with a transparent shaders..). It's better to use the tools in the particle system. For the shaders, it's just a matter of stacking correctly a series of mix shaders controlled by an image texture.

Comment: Is there a better way to get the hairs to be distributed throughout the mesh without weight paint?

Comment: You can use, for example, [a texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szXLv.gif) to control the density of the hairs if you need a vertex-indipendent solution

Comment: Will the density be affected by how light the shading is as well? If you use grey, than black, it will be not as dense?

Comment: Yes, it works that way.

Comment: Why is the hair not going to the locations on the texture? Do you need to set up any nodes? https://i.imgur.com/rTfeTKA.png

Comment: Is the hair distribution the core of the question? If it is, I would suggest to edit the body and the title in this sense, otherwise I would suggest to open a separate question about that so everyone can find it and contribute.